# Add proxy element to applicationHost.config in system.webServer section via Powershell

Tags: powershell, iis, powershell-5.0, web-administration

I am trying to add `<proxy enabled="true" />` element under `system.webServer` section.

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter '/system.webServer/proxy' -Name . -Value @{ enabled="true" }
```

Above command does nothing.

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter '/system.webServer' -Name 'proxy' -Value @{ enabled="true" }
```

Above command throws error: `Property proxy is not found on  system.webServer`

```
Add-WebConfiguration -Filter '/system.webServer/proxy' -Value @{ enabled="true" }
```

Also does nothing.

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter '/system.webServer/proxy' -Name 'enabled' -Value 'true'
```

Shows warning: `Target configuration object '/system.webServer/proxy is not found at path 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'.`

I find these commands very counterintuitive. What is the right way to add new element?

EDIT:

I was testing these commands on Windows 2019 Core with default IIS 10.0

I have Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5

I can setup proxy on Win2012 with command `appcmd set config -section:system.webServer/proxy /enabled:"true" /commit:apphost`, but the same command doesn't work on Win2019. It shows error `Unknown config section "system.webServer/proxy".` So, this setting may be not valid for IIS 10.0

Comment: Have you installed ARR on Windows Server 2019? If not, that setting won't be recognized (and the error is expected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to make sure ARR has install like Lex Li said.

Then try this powershell command, it can work well in my server 2019.

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.webServer/proxy" -name "enabled" -value "True"
```

[image]